# Wrong file path when saving through "customize" interface

Tags: init-file, customize

I've just started using emacs recently and it's fist time i try to configure it.
I have following setup under Windows 7:

**"...\emacs\config\.emacs"**

**"...\emacs\emacs-bin-w64-25.0.94-O2\..."**

**"...\emecs\emacs.exe"** - this is actually a shortcut to emacs located in above directory.

Shortcut target:

**"...\emacs\emacs-bin-w64-25.0.94-O2\emacs\bin\runemacs.exe -q -l config.emacs"**

Start in:

**"...\emacs\"**

Above works just fine but I would like to be able to change settings using *Custom* mode. So in **.emacs** I've added following line:

```
(user-init-file (concat (pwd) "config/.emacs")
```

But it turns out that with this setting the "1 = Save for future session" option is gone when I try to save changes done in Custom mode.

So I added next line after that:

```
(setq custom-file user-init-file)
```

Now both variables store correct path to **.emacs** file. At least they store path I expect which is:

**"...\emacs\config\.emacs"**

And "1 = Save for future session" option is available back again but the problem occur when I try to use it. The minibufer give me this:

> A buffer is visiting
>   .../emacs/emacs-bin-w64-25.0.94-O2/emacs/share/info/Directory
>   .../emacs/config/Directory
>   .../emacs/config/.emacs; proceed? n user-error:
>   Aborted

Basically it adds two additional paths to the one I specified. Why is that and how to fix it?

Comment: Documentation says `pwd` return "current default directory". Why I souldn't use it?

Comment: My god... You were right. I missed that "Directory" word was included in there. Post answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(setq foo (pwd))`, then `C-h v foo`.

The value is not just a directory string.  It's a directory string preceded by `"Directory "`.

Don't use `pwd`; use variable `default-directory`.